# No access to Wild West and Pirate Seas

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I've played all 24 levels of Ancient Egypt and defeated Dr. Zomboss, but there is no access to Pirate seas or Wild West. I tried updating the game and resetting my iPhone but no joy.

Before I give up and delete the game and redownload, I'd like to check that my copy really is defective (and it's not just me making some basic error) because I've bought extra plants in the Zen Garden using the gems that I've won and don't want to lose them unless it can't be avoided.

Comment: I seem to remember there being a minimum star requirement to move on from Ancient Egypt, but then I seem to remember that requirement being removed at some point.  Is there a big star past the final level in Ancient Egypt?

Comment: stupid question but do you have a world key?

Comment: I was under the impression that pvz2 went crazy with microtransactions. Do you have to buy them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking on the locked world? If you click on the Wild West or the Pirate Seas, then if you have the key, there will be a button where it says "unlock".

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I figured it out.  Hit the green back arrow at the very top left of the screen when you are on the Egypt land.  It brings you to a screen where you see all the islands you can open.  I was stuck forever too...looking for a place to unlock pirate seas within the Egypt levels.